# How to get first and last postdata from custom post type in wordpress?

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

In the wordpress theme I have created custom  post type. In this custom post type images are attached using image upload metabox field. For this I can create any number of posts( images).

At the front end ,inside my main template I got those images in loop using following wordpress functon:

```
    <?php

    global $post;
    $args = array(
    'post_type' =>'Imagespost',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC' );

    $image_posts = get_posts($args); ?>

    <?php
        if($image_posts) { ?>

      <div id="bigImages">
      <ul class ="image-list">

           <?php

            foreach($image_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);

             // get attached image URL from image upload metabox field.
             $full_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_image', true);

           echo  '<a href=" ' . $full_image . '" class="playlist-btn">';
          ?>
              <?php endforeach;?>

            </ul>
       </div>

 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

In this way I am storing each attached image as $full_image inside loop and using it as href attribute for further display . same way I want to store only first image or last image as a variable depends if `ORDER: as ascending (ASC) or descending (DESC).` How can I grab only the data from first or last post from custom post type?

Answer (score 2):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>'Imagespost',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC' );

$image_posts = get_posts($args);
```

Add posts_per_page = 1. 
This returns only one post.

Use this query twice one with order ASC and one with order DESC. And it returns only one post.

Or second solution is :

Count number of posts returned. i.e

```
$count = count($image_posts);
$image_posts[0] // return first ImagePost
$image_posts[$count-1] // returns last ImagePost.
```